# Is PreparedStatement changing Strings in java?

Tags: java, sql

PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(query);

```
      String S_DATE = s_date+" 00:00:00 CET";
      Timestamp S = Timestamp.valueOf(S_DATE);


      String E_DATE = e_date+" 00:00:00 CET";
      Timestamp E = Timestamp.valueOf(E_DATE);


      prest.setTimestamp(1,S);
      prest.setTimestamp(2,E);
      prest.setTimestamp(3,S);
      prest.setTimestamp(4,E);
      prest.setTimestamp(5,S);      
      prest.setTimestamp(6,E);  
      rs = prest.executeQuery();
```

//something like that instead??  but im not sure where to use setTimestamp().. thank you so much for your time and efford btw!

Comment: A couple of things here; 1) The way you're creating timestamps implies that you're not storing them as UTC in the database.  Especially as the specified timezone is (potentially) subject to DST, this _may_ cause problems (depends heavily on RDBMS vendor/version).  Generally, UTC is recommended, especially for anything touching multiple timezones.  2)  Please read [this blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for issues with `BETWEEN` and variable-precision types (like timestamps).

Answer (score 0):

What you pass as parameter is not a string parameter. It's a part of the query itself. The parameter should only be `2007-10-10 00:00:00 CET` The rest should be in the query itself. By doing what you're doing, the query will in fact be

```
WHERE S_DATE BETWEEN 'TIMESTAMP ''2007-10-10 00:00:00 CET''' ...
```

But instead of passing timestamps as strings and using database functions to transform these strings to timestamps, you'd better pass `java.sql.Timestamp` instances using `setTimestamp()`.